# Restricting which parameters passed in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

First off the **Question:** is there a Jenkins plugin that would allow us to select which of the current build parameters we want to pass to a downstream job?

**Our problem:**
We have a build with many jobs that install and configure system and then run multiple test suites on it.  There are certain parameters, that are set in the beginning, that need to be passed to all the downstream jobs.  We have been doing it with the [Parametrized Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) using "Current build parameters" option.  Each job was passing "current build parameters" down.

The problem with this approach is that the downstream jobs define additional parameters that have the same names but require *different* values.  To illustrate, let's say we have job `testsuite4` that defines parameter CONFIG_FILE and sets it to VALUE1.  Then job `testsuite5` defines the same parameter, CONFIG_FILE, but sets it to VALUE2.  When passing "current build parameters" between jobs, VALUE1 will prevail and overwrite VALUE2 of the downstream `testsuite5` job.

One obvious way to solve it, is to rename the parameters that are job specific.  However, test suites come from different teams, have many parameters and we want to minimize customizing incoming test jobs, if possible.  I've been looking for a plugin that would allow us to select which parameters from the current build we want to pass.  Some way to mark `global` parameters that should be passed, versus `local` parameters, that shouldn't.  Can't find such a thing.

For the time being, I put all the `global` parameters in a file (on NFS, since jobs run on different slaves) and only pass "Parameters from properties file" between the test suite jobs.  Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Run condition plugin - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin might be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  While the plugin looks interesting, it does not address this particular issue.  It seems to me that passing one parameters file along is cleaner than having additional logical conditions on different jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)** plugin.

What you've linked to in your OP is "job parameters", not a plugin, but you are talking about "Current build parameters" which *is* a feature of **[Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)** plugin. I will assume you got confused with terminology and *do* have the plugin installed.

If you want to cherry-pick parameters to pass, you can chose the **Predefined parameters** option. In here, you explicitly specify the parameters you want passed to downstream job.

The format is such:

```
param_of_downstream_job=value
```

If you want a global parameter that is same between upstream and downstream jobs, for example `myGlobalParam`, you would do:

```
myGlobalParam=${myGlobalParam}
```

If you want to pass upstream parameter `myParam`, but call it `myParamFromUpstream` in the downstream job:

```
myParamFromUpstream=${myParam}
```

You could even combine parameters, or use plain text in place of 'value':

```
combinedParam=mytest_${param1}-${param2}
```

<strike>A final note: **these parameters (on left side) do NOT need to be configured in downstream jobs**. If they happen to match an already existing parameter in downstream job by the same name, it will override that. If there is no such existing parameter in the downstream job, it will simply create it (and you access it in downstream job like you would access any other parameter).</strike>
The above paragraph is no longer true for latest versions of the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  Yes, we have parametrized trigger plugin.  We are using a solution of putting all the "global" parameters in a file and passing that around between jobs.  Each individual job can then define other parameters as they want but what's passed down, is always just our global parameters file that's residing on a nfs share.  This solution keeps all the parameters in one place (those that are dynamic are updated by setup jobs).  We find it's easier to maintain, than having each job pass specific parameters.